# How to listen for the 'after init' event of a View in YUI 3.11

Tags: events, yui

Inside a YUI view I have the following methods:

```
    initializer: function () {            
        this.after('init', this.onInitComplete, this);                        
    },

    onInitComplete: function (e) {
        console.log('onInitComplete');
        var list = this.checkGroupList = new CheckGroupList();

        var group1 = new Y.CheckGroupModel();            
        var group2 = new Y.CheckGroupModel();            
        var group3 = new Y.CheckGroupModel();            

        list.add(group1);
        list.add(group2);
        list.add(group3);            
        this.reset();
    },
```

Why onInitComplete is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your listener isn't being called is that YUI is trying to optimize the `init` event because it is too expensive when creating lots of instances of `Y.Base`. The `init` event s normally responsible for calling all the initializers. But when there are no listeners the initializer functions are called directly without firing the `init` the event. Since you're adding a listener in an initializer, YUI assumes there are no listeners to the event and doesn't fire it.

I suggest you either do what you were doing in the listener directly in the initializer or add a listener to the event from the class constructor.

Comment: I'm actually doing it in the initializer now, but how can I add a listener in the class constructor?

Comment: You can only if you're not using `Y.Base.create`. Here's an issue in the YUI bug tracker where you can follow the state of this bug: https://github.com/yui/yui3/issues/1043